# Merge random number of dicts in list

Tags: python, dictionary

The task is to create a list of a random number of dicts (from 2 to 10)

- dict's random numbers of keys should be letter, dict's values should
  be a number (0-100), example: `[{'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'g': 11}, {'a': 3, 'c': 35, 'g': 42}]`
- get a previously generated list of dicts and create one common dict:

if dicts have same key, we will take max value, and rename key with dict number with max value
if key is only in one dict - take it as is,
example: `{'a_1': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 35, 'g_2': 42}`

I've written the following code:

```
from random import randint, choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

final_dict, indexes_dict = {}, {}

rand_list = [{choice(ascii_lowercase): randint(0, 100) for i in range(len(ascii_lowercase))} for j in range(randint(2, 10))]

for dictionary in rand_list:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key not in final_dict:
            final_dict.update({key: value}) # add first occurrence 
        else:
            if value < final_dict.get(key):
                #TODO indexes_dict.update({:})
                continue
            else:
                final_dict.update({key: value})
                #TODO indexes_dict.update({:}) 

for key in indexes_dict:
    final_dict[key + '_' + str(indexes_dict[key])] = final_dict.pop(key)

print(final_dict)
```

I only need to add some logic in order to keep indexes of final_dict values (created the separated dict for it).

I'm wondering if exists some more Pythonic way in order to solve such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

This approach seems completely reasonable.
I, personally, would probably go around this way, however:

```py
final_dict, tmp_dict = {},  {}

#Transform from list of dicts into dict of lists.
for dictionary in rand_list:
  for k, v in dictionary.items():
    tmp_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

#Now choose only the biggest one
for k, v in tmp_dict.items():
  if len(v) > 1:
    final_dict[k+"_"+str(v.index(max(v))+1)] = max(v)
  else: final_dict[k] = v[0]
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer! Could you help to fix the following error, please?

for k, v in dictionary.items:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry, forgot a pair of brackets and some other bits and pieces. That's what happens when you write your code on a phone, kids!

Answer (score 0):

You will need some auxiliary data structure to keep track of unrepeated keys. This uses `collections.defaultdict` and `enumerate` to aid the task:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge(dicts):
    helper = defaultdict(lambda: [-1, -1, 0])  # key -> max, index_max, count
    for i, d in enumerate(dicts, 1):  # start indexing at 1
        for k, v in d.items():
            helper[k][2] += 1  # always increase count
            if v > helper[k][0]:
                helper[k][:2] = [v, i]  # update max and index_max
    # build result from helper data structure
    result = {}
    for k, (max_, index, count) in helper.items():
        key = k if count == 1 else "{}_{}".format(k, index)
        result[key] = max_   
    return result

>>> merge([{'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'g': 11}, {'a': 3, 'c': 35, 'g': 42}])
{'a_1': 5, 'b': 7, 'g_2': 42, 'c': 35}
```

Comment: thanks! by the way, I have one more idea. we can check the first character of key in the result dict

Comment: Unsure what you mean or what end this would serve :)